# References and results for the eigenvalues of Ricci tensor

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ricci-curvature

I am looking for references or results that gives estimates for every eigenvalue of the Ricci tensor. For example, the least eigenvalue is related to the minimum of the Ricci curvature, what can we say about the others? It was a surprise that a standard google search leaded to no satisfactory result.

If needed, one can assume that the Ricci tensor is positive definite (the case when the sectional curvature is positive).

There is a way on approaching this problem, although I don't how fruitful it its. For example, in harmonic coordinates
$$R_{ij} = -\dfrac{1}{2}\Delta g_{ij} + o(\Gamma_{ij}),$$
where $o(\Gamma_{ij})$ means that on a fixed point one can assume that
$$o(\Gamma_{ij})(p) = 0.$$
Therefore, this is somehow equivalent to solve
$$-\dfrac{1}{2}\Delta g_{ij} + o(\Gamma_{ij}) = \lambda g_{ij},$$
and the problem reduces almost to the problem of estimating the eigenvalues of the Laplace-Beltrami operator.